# Testing if Angular asynchronous function returns a promise fails in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine, promise

I am trying to test if an asynchronous call returns a promise and it is failing. The function I am testing:

```
findOne: (collection, query) ->
  @find collection, query
```

where `find` is function that simply makes a call to `$http.post`

The spec that is failing:

```
describe "#findOne", () ->

it "should return a promise", () ->
  expect(entitySvc.findOne.then).toBeDefined()
```

Why is this failing? `find` is simply returning the `httpPromise` object returned by `$http.post`.

Comment: Can you post the body of find? Are you mocking your httpBackend?

Comment: No, I am not mocking `$httpBackend` in the spec. Here is the body of `find`:

    find: (collection, query) -> 
      $http.post server + "/api/v1/findJson/#{collection}", query

Comment: I don't understand why I need to mock `$httpBackend` if I'm already mocking that in my test for `find`:


          it "should make a request to the correct URL", () ->
    $httpBackend.expectPOST(server+"/api/v1/findJson/blocks",{}).respond(200,{id:1})
      mySvc.find collection, queryNone
      $httpBackend.flush()

I tried mocking `$httpBackend` in my `findOne` spec, that generated an error `No pending request to flush !`

Comment: I am not familiar with CoffeeScript, so this could be way wrong, but *are you calling the function*? It seems to me you are not; if so, how do you expect it to return the promise?

Comment: I think Nikos is right. `findOne.then` won't be defined because `findOne` was not called in the expectation.

Comment: I think that might have had something to do with it. I also added an `$httpBackend` mock and passed the parameters to `findOne`. Thanks for your help. Unit Testing angular is not easy!

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the method. Note the parenthases after `findOne()`

```
describe "#findOne", () ->

it "should return a promise", () ->
  expect(entitySvc.findOne().then).toBeDefined()
```